# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on moving jMapViewer

Tags: java, jmapviewer

I'm trying to update markers on a jMapViewer once every 5 seconds. This seems to be working fine until you move the map. At this point it throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

I believe this is to do with the different processes trying to access the map markers list at the same time but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadUnits();
        }
    }, 5 * 1000, 5 * 1000);

   private void loadUnits() {      
    String query = "SELECT callsign, currentlat,currentlon,previouslat,previouslon,    mobile, uniticon FROM unit WHERE isdeleted=0;";
    rs = DBase.runQuery(query);
    kit.removeAllMapMarkers();
    MapMarkerUnit x;
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
           x = new MapMarkerUnit(rs.getDouble("currentlat"),rs.getDouble("currentlon"));
           if (rs.getInt("mobile") == 1) x.setMovement(true);
           else x.setMovement(false);
           x.setIconName(rs.getString("uniticon"));
           x.setPriority(1);
           kit.addMapMarker(x);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Kieran

Comment: What is `rs`? Can you give a MWE?

Comment: RS is a ResultSet pulled from a MySQL database. Sorry MWE? A little new to this.

Comment: Minimum Working Example, in other words code one can compile and experiment with...

Comment: @CommuSoft Thanks - have updated my question with more of the code. I'm looking at your code below - hopefully between that and google I'll be able to understand it.

Comment: [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) may be an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `Semaphore`, `Mutex`, a **monitor** (with `synchronized` in the method signature) or a **lock** (`synchronize` on object). There exist *lock-free* and *wait-free* approaches as well, but these algorithms are more complex and are only useful under special circumstances.

---

**Examples**

The problem is probably that `map` is modified concurrently, using a **lock**, one can write:

```
synchronize(map) {
    map.removeAllMapMarkers();
    MapMarkerUnit x;
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
           x = new MapMarkerUnit(rs.getDouble("currentlat"),rs.getDouble("currentlon"));
           if (rs.getInt("mobile") == 1) x.setMovement(true);
           else x.setMovement(false);
           x.setIconName(rs.getString("uniticon"));
           x.setPriority(1);
           map.addMapMarker(x);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }
}
```

This results in the fact that only one `Thread` can access `map` (if it runs this code). If one thread is in the `synchronize` block, all other threads wait at the beginning of the block.

A problem with this approach is the so called *Readers-Writers problem*. Most datastructures allow to be read by multiple *Readers*, but if some *Thread* want to write something (modify something as well), no *Reader* can be active. In that case one uses a `ReadWriteLock`:

```
private ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void writeSomething() {
   rwl.writeLock().lock();
   try {
      //Modify/write something
   } finally {
      rwl.writeLock().unlock();
   }
}

public String readSomething() {
   rwl.readLock().lock();
   try {
      //Read something
   } finally {
      rwl.readLock().unlock();
   }
}
```

You better use `finally` blocks so that even if an `Exception` is thrown you still unlock the lock, otherwise no other object will be able to enter the *critical section*.

Comment: Looking into this problem further. map is an object of class jMapViewer. This stores a list of map markers in a List<MapMarker>. It then iterates through this to redraw the map markers. The problem appears to be that the map.removeAllMarkers() removes them while this is happening.

Comment: Your example above makes sense but I'm not sure how to implement it. synchronize(map) doesn't appear to work as the iterator is inside map already.

Comment: @KieranS: in that case you should lock the `map` before retrieving the list of markers and only unlock (end the scope) if no action will be performed on that list anymore.

Comment: That worked - performing the operations on a separate list. Thanks for all your help and time!

Comment: @KieranS: You should also check if the action is eventually repeated every time. Locks can cause *deadlocks*: where two or more threads wait for each other to perform an action.